# iOS App Portrait and Landscape Views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to make and iOS app with both portrait and landscape views, but if I open it and change the orientation to Landscape, some buttons got offscreen, after going to IB and reordering the buttons, in Portrait they go off screen.

After googling, I dont have ANY ideia how to 'change' views according to orientation.

Could you guys give me some help?
Ah, also, Apple Support Documents seems pretty useless to me :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a method

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{}
```

which is useful in such cases.

Comment: As I said, I dont have idea what to do with this :S

Comment: I use this method in my viewControllers to redefine positions (frame redefinition) of buttons according to the position of a device. Not sure whether IB offers better solution, but this is done programmatically.

Comment: Hm.. I've tried here, but i can't access the 'X', 'Y', 'width' and 'height' by using "button.x", how do you do that?

Comment: Nevermind, find the '.origin.x' thanks anyway for the clues :D

Answer (score 0):

You should change autosizing properties in IB (they're in the same place where frame size is) or change `autoresizingMask` properties of your inner views and controls programmatically. This controls what happens to the elements of your screen after it gets resized (for example when the screen is rotating). You can glue your components to left or right or both, top or bottom or both and similar. Play with it, it's pretty powerful and you don't need any code for that if what they can do is enough.
[image: Autosizing properties in a screenshot]